# Kotlin incompatibility error with Firebase Auth KTX Granule Kotlin module

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle

I am getting the following error when trying to build my Android project with Kotlin version 1.6.0 and firebase_bom_version 32.2.3:

**`java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_auth_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.`**

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, restarting Android Studio, and invalidating the caches, but the error persists.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Additional information: My project's build.gradle file is belown.

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'kotlin-android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
   id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
   id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
   id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx_version"

    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-ktx")

   // Google Play Core Dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:$google_play_core_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core-ktx:$google_play_core_ktx_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
 }
```

Project's Gradle

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
   ext.core_ktx_version = "1.6.0"
   ext.firebase_bom_version = "32.2.3"
   ext.core_ktx_version = "1.8.0"

  // Google Services Dependencies.
   ext.google_services_version = "4.3.14"
   ext.google_play_core_version = '1.10.3'
   ext.google_play_core_ktx_version = "1.8.1"



   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version")
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help with this issue! I will post any additional information that you need in the comments section below.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade the version of Kotlin to `1.6.0`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, tried that. Did not work.